# How to create POST request to Jira

Tags: java, rest, jira

I need to create application which interacts with Jira (it should parse Excel file and input data into Jira).

My first guess is to use REST API. However, it seems that there is no REST API for Jira and I'm not sure whether whether such approach is possible/eligable in this case or some better solution exists (like `HttpURLConnection`).

I will appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Sounds like you should use selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A REST API is available for Jira - here's a link to the REST API intro https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/intro/